# Как обезопасить связь пользователей?

Tags: безопасность

Мы пишем мессенджер и надо написать голосовой и видео чат. Клиент написан, но есть вопрос в плане безопасности связи. Возможно ли сделать связь через Тор Браузер?

Просто если возможно же передавать текстовые сообщения через Тор, то можно ли как-то провернуть подобное и с голосовыми и видео-связью, который использовал бы службы Tor onion в качестве своей базовой сети. Он обеспечивал криптографически безопасный обмен  сообщениями. Характеристики луковых сервисов Tor гарантируют, что весь трафик между клиентами будет зашифрован и что очень сложно определить, кто с кем общается и где физически находится данный клиент, но страдает от утечки метаданных.

Comment: Не специалист, но через тор связь не очень, там скорость будет плохая. Не проще ли напрямую клиентов соединить, а ключи можно безопасно передавать как это в https делается

Comment: @gil9red нет,  Тор достаточно быстро сообщения доставлет( мы тестировали). Нам  именно видео связь нужна

Comment: А сколько было узлов между начальной и конечной? Были они в пределах одной страны или нескольких?

Answer (score 2):

Позвольте сделать 2 замечания. Резберем по косточкам фразу

"Характеристики луковых сервисов Tor гарантируют, что весь трафик между клиентами будет зашифрован и что очень сложно определить, кто с кем общается и где физически находится данный клиент"

1. Чтобы трафик был зашифрован - Tor не нужен. Если у вас есть end-to-end шифрование (то есть, попросту говоря, если Вы используете https) - то трафик уже зашифрован.
2. "очень сложно определить, кто с кем общается и где физически находится данный клиент" - и здесь надо добавить "*в предположении, что бОльшая часть нод Tor'а не находится под контролем стороны, желающей осуществлять наблюдение за сетью*"

Вообще говоря, у вас две задачи, решение первой - тривиально, решение второй - довольно сложнО.

Я не хочу умничать, но для видео и аудио важна такая характеристика сети, как джиттер - или "фазовое дрожание цифрового сигнала данных". Вам надо не просто быстро передавать пакеты, а еще и делать так, чтобы передача велась со стабильными характеристиками. На уровне Tor - это нерешаемая проблема.

Вы можете сделать очень простую штуку для эксперимента: есть же видеосвязь через webrtc. Это работает прямо в браузере.

Можно "на коленках" поднять сервер, устроить через него звонок.

Потом добавить этот сервер в onion - сеть, и попробовать сделать то же самое через tor. Результат покажет Вам, реальна ли такая связь.

Причем, я не хочу быть пессимистом. Будет прекрасно, если это получится. Ведь, к примеру, до того момента, когда skype сделал звонки (а впоследствии и видеозвонки) через интернет - *применив для этого P2P сеть!* - люди тоже не верили, что это реально. ( *ну, это было еще до того, как microsoft купила скайп, и он превратился в ту какашку, которой является сейчас* )

Но, мне кажется, что здесь нужно пойти на некие компромиссы. Мне таким компромиссом видится не двусторонняя аудио-видеосвязь, а сравнительно быстрая передача голосовых и видеосообщений - этакий push-to-talk, "навернутый" поверх tor.